# Trying create an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

            [NT_NOTAFINAL] => 10.00          
            [M_DESCRICAO] => ARTE          
            [PE_DESCRICAO] => 1 BIMESTRE           
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [NT_NOTAFINAL] => 10.00          
            [M_DESCRICAO] => ARTE          
            [PE_DESCRICAO] => 2 BIMESTRE           
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [NT_NOTAFINAL] => 10.00          
            [M_DESCRICAO] => ARTE          
            [PE_DESCRICAO] =>3 BIMESTRE           
        )

)
```

Now I'm trying create an associative array to return JSON something like this:

```
"Materia":[{"descricao":"ARTE", "Notas":["1 BIMESTRE":10.00, "2 BIMESTRE":10.00, "3 BIMESTRE":10.00]}]
```

I don't know how I could create this associative array to this JSON result from this array that I'm posting.

I'm trying create like this but the result what I need does not return

```
$notas = '';
$materia = '';
foreach($lista as $value){
    if($value["M_DESCRICAO"] != $materia){
        $materia = $value["M_DESCRICAO"];         
    } 
    $notas = array("Descricao"=>$materia, "Notas"=>array($value["PE_DESCRICAO"]=>$value["NT_NOTAFINAL"]));


}
$result = array("Materia"=>array($notas));
echo json_encode($result);
```

The result to what I'm trying is

```
{
  "Materia": [
    {
      "Descricao": "ARTE",
      "Notas": {
        "3 BIMESTRE": "10.00"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How could I create this associative array to return this JSON like I need ?

**Edit**

```
$notas = array();
$materia = '';
$materia_array = array();
foreach($lista as $value){
    if($materia == ''){
        $materia = $value["M_DESCRICAO"];
    }
    if($value["M_DESCRICAO"] != $materia){
        array_push($materia_array, (array("Descricao"=>$materia,"Notas"=>$notas)));
        $notas = array();
        $materia = $value["M_DESCRICAO"];
    }else{        
        array_push($notas, array($value["PE_DESCRICAO"]=>$value["NT_NOTAFINAL"]));
    }


}
$result = array("Materia"=>$materia_array);
echo json_encode($result);
```

**Result**

```
{
  "Materia": [
    {
      "Descricao": "ARTE",
      "Notas": [
        {
          "1 BIMESTRE": "10.00"
        },
        {
          "2 BIMESTRE": "10.00"
        },
        {
          "3 BIMESTRE": "10.00"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Descricao": "C.SOCIAIS",
      "Notas": [
        {
          "2 BIMESTRE": "10.00"
        },
        {
          "3 BIMESTRE": "9.50"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Descricao": "CIÊNCIAS E P. S.",
      "Notas": [
        {
          "2 BIMESTRE": "9.50"
        },
        {
          "3 BIMESTRE": "10.00"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I do not know what you are trying to achieve. Which is the desired output? The json array with "Materia" ?

Comment: @Jan `"Materia":[{"descricao":"ARTE", "Notas":["1 BIMESTRE":10.00, "2 BIMESTRE":9.50, "3 BIMESTRE":10.00]}]`

Comment: Why do you want the output to be `9.50` in the `2 BIMESTRE` if in the array it's `10`? typo? Also, you are replacing the value of the key `Notas` every loop. What you want is probably save the value from key `Notas` in an array (`tmp[] = ...`) and then add it to the `Materia`. right?

Comment: Do you want to loop over the array until "M_DESCRICAO" changes? That is, put all values to an array until there is another M_DESCRICAO ? A `while` loop would do this.

Comment: @FirstOne you allright, I edited the output. All is 10.00, I posted with this error, now is ok.

Comment: @Jan, yep, there is anothers results with M_DESCRICAO. and each M_DESCRICAO has Notas

Comment: Can you provide the expected result for more than one `Materia`?

Comment: @FirstOne, the result(output) is the same JSON, only change M_DESCRICAO because has others and PE_DESCRICAO because to each M_DESCRICAO has one or more informations example: `1 BIMESTRE, 2 BIMESTRE, 3 BIMESTRE, 4 BIMESTRE etc...`. To each PE_DESCRICAO have values `10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've refactored your last edit to remove some code duplication and complexity.

```
$result = array();

foreach ($lista as $value) {
    $materia = $value['M_DESCRICAO'];

    if (!isset($result[$materia])) {
        $result[$materia] = array(
            'Descricao' => $materia, 
            'Notas'     => array()
        );
    }

    $result[$materia]['Notas'][] = array(
        $value['PE_DESCRICAO'] => $value['NT_NOTAFINAL']
    );
}

$result = array('Materia' => array_values($result));

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my comment, this would be the code to push all notes to an array as long as the `M_DESCRICAO` does not change, so the starting array `$lista` needs to be ordered first. Is this what you were after (code is not tested, office computer :-))?

```
$notas = $materia = null;
$result = $tmp = array();
$len = count($lista);
for ($i=0;$i<$len;$i++) {
    $notas = array();
    $materia = $lista[$i]["M_DESCRICAO"];
    while (($materia == $lista[$i+1]["M_DESCRICAO"]) && ($i < ($len -1))) {
        $notas[$lista[$i]["PE_DESCRICAO"]] = $lista[$i]["NT_NOTAFINAL"];
        $i++;
    }
    // now $notas holds all corresponding entries
    $tmp[] = array("Descricao"=>$materia, "Notas" => $notas);
}
$result = array("Materia"=>array($tmp));
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I worked out an untested (there might be some errors, but logically it should work) piece of code, but it might help you:

```
    $notas;
    $materia = '';
    $materia_array;
    foreach($lista as $value){
        if($materia == '')
            $materia = $value["M_DESCRICAO"];
        if($value["M_DESCRICAO"] != $materia){
            array_push($materia_array, (array("Descricao"=>$materia,"Notas"=>$notas));
             unset($notas); //<--------
             $notas = array();//<--------
            $materia = $value["M_DESCRICAO"];         
        }
        else
        {
            array_push($notas, array($value["PE_DESCRICAO"]=>$value["NT_NOTAFINAL"]))
        }

    }
    $result = array("Materia"=>$materia_array);
    echo json_encode($result);
```

This should work for multiple `M_DESCRICAO` values

Comment: I'm following your sample does works partially because now it are repeating "Notas". I edited the post with JSON output and how I try

Comment: If i understand you correct you now want to remove the {} around the whole output and inside your "Notas". Is that correct?

Comment: exactly ...if you look the first result is ok with `1 BIMESTRE, 2 BIMESTRE, 3 BIMESTRE` but the others are repeated Notas. understand ?

Comment: Okey to fix the problem with $notas you just need to add the 2 lines of code i added on my answer (marked with <-----).

Comment: thanks for your help. Your fix works with first result, look at edit only first result return "1 BIMESTRE" and others does haven't, the other results started from "2 BIMESTRE", how can I solve it ?

Comment: i dont see any problem codewise... are you sure the data you are using isn´t just starting at 2 BIMESTRE?